# USB Relay unit programming

Tags: c#, serial-port

Never did any kind of embedded or hardware programming, I mainly deal with web applications.  But we have the need to turn off / on a usb relay possibly in C#.  I obtained a PDF of the device we are buying [here](http://www.sigma-shop.com/manuals/usb_one_relay_box_manual.pdf).

In the document there is some sample code such as:

```
private void button1_ON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0xFF, 0x01, 0x01 }, 0, 3);
}
private void button1_OFF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
serialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0xFF, 0x01, 0x00 }, 0, 3);
}
```

Question is, wouldn't I need a DLL / some sort of library to access `serialPort1`, sorry for the rubbish question but I'm just not certain how something like this works.  I am not seeing any indication from the pdf or the website about any sort of library I would need to reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you just need to use the [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class. As I recall the USB device will probably register itself as a serial port called 'COM##' where the hashes represent digits. You will need to supply the port name and the bit rate.

Comment: So once the USB device registers would I just instantiate a `SerialPort` object and pass the port name and bit rate to get the handle, namely `serialPort1` as in the example above?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I haven't tried to do this in .net, but the pattern looks similar to how I did it before .net. Also, you could probably poll the available serial ports to see which is your device.

Answer (score 2):

.NET comes with a `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class that sucks pretty badly.  That's what is being used in the example.  If you only need to send data and don't need to auto-detect the port, but instead have a stored configuration file, then it will probably work well enough.

If you are annoyed by the thought of spinning up worker threads and doing synchronization just to read from a serial port, and not being able to use Plug-and-Play port names generated by hotplug notifications, then I suggest using another serial API.  The Win32 one isn't bad, and I hope someday to be able to release my wrapper that I built for work that makes all these tasks easy (detecting when a device is plugged in, finding port based on the USB descriptor strings, raising UI events when data arrives).

Comment: Saying that the class sucks is putting it mildly.  It's a great way to have a hundred background threads spun up behind the scenes for you and causing loads of timing issues.  Ugh!

Answer (score 1):

The FTDI manufactures usb/serial chipsets.  USB devices that use their chipsets will show up on your computer as a Serial device (COM port).  If not packaged w/ the product software, FTDI has a driver that you can download from their website.  Fairly standard.

The driver links are available on that product PDF. http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm

When installed, you just communicate via serial.